# mysql server has gone away

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data 50,000 rows with one query therefore Server is going away. I have tried to change max_allowed_packet but its not changing. Any advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean it is going away?  Like freezing up?

Comment: Wow, the server disappeared? You mean there's a hole in your server rack with wires hanging down? That's a first :)

Comment: Make sure you compliant with all the possible causes listed here :
[why mysql gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: "mysql server has gone away" is the actual error message, for those not familiar with MySQL

Comment: That's one spaced-out error message written by someone who's drunk too much coffee and not had enough sleep.

Comment: @bemace I know but it's still funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked mysqls's wait_timeout time?  Also, what are you using to import the records (a script, a sql editor, the command line)?  Php forexample uses it's own connect_timeout set in php.ini that will cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: I am trying to run script with sql editor. I haven't checked timeout. Please tell me how can I set timeout;

Comment: What is the editor?  Many of them have their own timeout settings.

Comment: Maybe this link will help: http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs4420.html

Answer (score 1):

It's probably either taking so long to build the query that the server disconnects due to idle timeout, or it's taking so long to transmit that it thinks there's been an error.  The best method is probably to break your insert into groups of 25-100 records.

Comment: Ah. It will take a lot of time. Because I have 1000,000 records in total which are splited by 50,000

Comment: When using a perl or php script to load data, using inserts with 25-100 records was faster than trying to load them all at once for me.  YMMV, do you own benchmarks

Answer (score 1):

[There](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) look for wait_timeout and some mysql_ping and a few more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have set max_allowed_packet=64 in my.ini and restarted server. Now its working fine. Thanks to all for help.